# Does Aptana have anything similar to Visual Studio's XML IntelliSense comments?

Tags: javascript, intellisense, aptana

Is there a way to customize my javascript's IntelliSense in Aptana IDE, a la Visual Studio xml comments?

Visual Studio Example:

```
function areaFunction(radiusParam)
{
    /// <summary>Determines the area of a cicle based on a radius parameter.</summary>
    /// <param name="radius" type="Number">The radius of the circle.</param>
    /// <returns type="Number">Returns a number that represents the area.</returns>
    var areaVal;
    areaVal = Math.PI * radiusParam * radiusParam;
    return areaVal;
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: There isn't a standard format for documentation comments in Javascript. Maybe try the Java style? `/** [documentation goes here] */` in front of the function declaration.

Comment: Good suggestion, but no dice.