# Does WebStorm have anything similar to Visual Studio's XML IntelliSense comments?

Tags: webstorm

Same question [as this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7923123/does-aptana-have-anything-similar-to-visual-studios-xml-intellisense-comments), but for WebStorm (NetBrains) IDE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can use jsDoc with Webstorm.

type in /** {Enter} and it'll provide you with a jsDoc template.